# how to change android project platform version

Tags: android, testing, device

i am doing an android project in platform 2.3.3 but for testing i have got a device in platform 1.5,is there any way to convert my project  from 2.3.3 to 1.5

copy paste doesn't working

Comment: go to manifest file and change sdk version .

Comment: The three answers so far are correct, but you need to make sure that application doesn't use any features that aren't available in Android 1.5 - that's the most critical and important thing to check.

Comment: yes most noteworthy are `matchparent` instead of `fillparent`.. and Passive provider

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In package explorer, you can right click the project name, go to properties, in the left column, click on "Android" and change the "Project Build Target" to the platform you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

IN your android manifest.xml

u will have to put `minSdkversion='1'` in ur application tag

Right click on your project---> properties ---> android---> select Android version 1.5

Create an emulator with target version 1.5

Answer (score 1):

Use Eclipse, right click on the workspace project property and select the Android SDK version from the Android option. You'll need to make sure you have installed that version from within Eclipse installed software, like you will have done for your later versions. Helps to set up a virtual emulator for that SDK too.